# how to create 3d dom in javascript using angular and ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, indexing, angularjs-ng-repeat

What I want to achieve is to create a 3 level in depth with angular and ng-repeat or ng-option but I am losing the track of $index because the second and third level are pointing to the same $index from level 1 not their own level. Accessing to the right index is important.

```
var A = [[[1],[2]],[[3],[4]],[[5],[6]]]

<ul> 
    <li ng-repeat="a in A track by indexA" ng-click="myFnA(indexA)">
        <ul> 
            <li ng-repeat="b in B track by indexB" ng-click="myFnB(indexB)"> 
                <ul> 
                    <li ng-repeat="c in C track by indexC" ng-click="myFnC(indexC)">

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [ng-init directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) to save indexes:

Also be sure that the nested `ng-repeat` uses the previous `ng-repeat` variable:

```
ng-repeat="itemA in A"     ng-init="indexA=$index"
ng-repeat="itemB in itemA" ng-init="indexB=$index"
ng-repeat="c     in itemB"
```

### The Demo

```js
angular.module("myApp",[]);

angular.module("myApp").controller("myVm", function($scope) {

  $scope.A = [[[1],[2]],[[3],[4]],[[5],[6]]];
    
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myVm">
  <h1>Nested ng-repeat Demo</h1>
    <ul> 
        <li ng-repeat="itemA in A" ng-init="indexA=$index"> 
           {{indexA}}:{{itemA}}
            <ul> 
                <li ng-repeat="itemB in itemA" ng-init="indexB=$index">
                    {{indexB}}:{{itemB}}
                    <ul> 
                        <li ng-repeat="c in itemB track by $index"> 
                           A[{{indexA}}][{{indexB}}][{{$index}}]={{c}}    
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can assign index to variable using `ng-init`

```
<ul> 
    <li ng-repeat="a in A track by $index" ng-init="indexA = $index"> <!--indexA is the index of a-->
        <ul> 
            <li ng-repeat="b in B track by $index"  ng-init="indexB = $index"><!--indexB is the index of b-->
                <ul> 
                    <li ng-repeat="c in C track by $index"  ng-init="indexC = $index"> <!--indexC is the index of c-->
                       {{indexA}}
                       {{indexB}}
                       {{indexC}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks, does it reflect the different value? they should not be the same. It makes my life alot easier if I pass $indexA to ng-change="myFn($indexA)"

Comment: it should reflect according to the relevant ng repeat index

Comment: I slightly changed the question based on your answer would you mind have quick look at and verify your answer works the same.

Comment: that will not work. you have to use `track by $index` ng repeat does not recognize the `indexA`